# Existence and uniqueness of solution of a nonlinear system

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, nonlinear-optimization, game-theory, root-systems, nash-equilibrium

I need a proof of the following result to calculate a Nash equilibrium in the Showcase Showdown game.

For all $n>1$, the system of equations
$$\left\{
\begin{aligned}
(1+e^{x}(-1+x))^{n-2}&=\dfrac{e^{y}\,\left(  -1+{\left(  1+e^{x}\,\left(
-1+y\right)  \right)  }^{n}\right)  +e^{x}\,n}{e^{x}\,\left(  1+e^{y
}\,\left(  -1+y\right)  \right)  \,n\,\left(  1+e^{x}\,\left(
-2+n+x\right)  \right)  }\\
{(1+e^{x}(-1+x))}^{n-1}&=\dfrac{-1+{\left(  1+e^{x}\,\left(  -1+y\right)
\right)  }^{n}+e^{x}\,{\left(  1+e^{x}\,\left(  -1+y\right)  \right)
}^{n-1}\,n}{e^{x}\,\left(  1+e^{y}\,\left(  -1+y\right)  \right)
\,n}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
has a unique solution $(\epsilon_n,\delta_n)\in[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with $\delta_n>\epsilon_n$.